# Trying to debug step through custom build configuration

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

I defined some custom build configurations and various web.config transforms to handle local conditions.  Some of these are meant to run locally and be debugged. 
 However, now stepping through code is disabled when these configurations are selected.  I have turned on "Enable Just My Code" and for the project I'm running I've went into the Build properties and checked "Define DEBUG constant".  "Optimize Code" is not checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your project properties, to the "Build" tab, ensure the build configuration you want to step through is selected in the dropdown at the top of the screen, click the "Advanced" button - In the dropdown labeled "Debugging Information" select "Full".

If you have enabled multiple start up projects for your solution, you'll need to repeat the steps for each project you wish to step through.

Comment: Really thanks for sharing your solution here, since it is resolved now, would you please mark it as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issue to find the answer easily.

Comment: Yeah, I had to wait two days.